# Where does information in the Field of Study attribute in Microsoft Academic API come from?

Tags: api, azure, search, azure-cognitive-services

I am using the Microsoft Academic API to extract information about articles (e.g. abstract) based on author. I can't find anywhere in the documentation where the 'Field of Study' keywords come from. Are they keywords provided by the author when they submitted the article, keywords associated with the journal, or something else? Any information on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Our fields of study are formal research topics that should be recognized by the broader research community. We currently have around 50k of them, and are looking to expand them.

As for how we label them on papers, we start with author and publisher supplied keywords and attempt to conflate them with our fields of study. If the conflation is of sufficient quality we expose the labels via our API.

We also leverage machine learning techniques to do additional labeling.